# Проблема с получением данных с api

Tags: reactjs, api, openweathermap

При попытке сделать асинхронный GET запрос к API получаю ошибку 401 (якобы я неавторизован, хотя личный ключ, который получил в личном кабинете в запросе указал правильно)
API называется OpenWeather. lon и lat это координаты города, их я получаю с другого API, с ними проблем нет. Запрос корректен, делал все по документации[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то все заработало, когда я сгенерировал новый ключ и указывал `lang=ru` в запросе.